# What is a safe but non-alarming proximity distance setting for SafeSky?

Tags: safety, general-aviation, mid-air-collision

I am using an app for General Aviation called Safesky. It works on cellular data, is free and provides a lot of the functionality that a dedicated box like Pilot Aware does.

However, I have set my range to 5NM and 2,500FT. Because I fly in busy airspace, this results in many proximity warnings, which causes extreme fatigue for me personally.

My logic for this setting, is that within 5NM, another aircraft could descend 2,500FT onto my level, but other more experienced pilots said this is not a distance to worry about.

**What would be a safe proximity setting in terms of vertical feet and horizontal distance for proximity alerts in GA?**

---

Please don't just provide numbers as an answer, but also provide the reasoning, facts and principles that lead to these numbers.

Comment: *Very* opinion based. OOI, which airfield do you fly from (if you're comfortable sharing that info)? I'm regularly in that section sandwiched between Luton/stansted and Heathrow/city (which is purported to be the busiest GA airspace in europe!) and I get traffic notifications within about 10NM, it's never bothered me too much. But that's because its just a backup for a good lookout. I know when I can just ignore it.

Comment: More in terms of answering your question, as im not that familiar with SafeSky - how do you get notifications from it? SkyDemon? Audio-only? Dedicated app on your phone screen?

Comment: Voting to close because of the opinion-based nature of the question. This is a good question for a pilot forum, though, and, personally, I am interested to know what the consensus is.

Comment: Don't agree that this is a purely opinion-based question. Answers may contain a level of opinion, but as long as they are supported by facts and principles, such opinion-based answers are valuable.

Comment: @Jamiec SafeSky is a mobile app that runs as a dedicated app on your phone. You can also run it as a split screen app on your tablet and it can stream it's data to/from your navigation app or other traffic related systems. https://www.safesky.app/ . Note: I'm not affiliated with SafeSky, just a happy user.

Comment: @DeltaLima Maybe not purely, but almost exclusively. For a start it's going to depend a lot on the airspace you're in, and the speed you're travelling. I know the answer to 1 of those but they should at very least be part of the question - otherwise it is absolutely opinions only.

Comment: @Jamiec, I am writing up an answer that gives a methodology to arrive at a reasonable number and allows for adjusting based on traffic environment and risk-appetite.

Comment: @Jamiec You can integrate SafeSky with SkyDemon (with a premium plan), it gives you audible and visual warnings, including a terrifying 'time to impact' countdown timer... hence my stress levels :D Flying at a collection of busy Microlight sights, I won't share specific airfield info, although I can tell you cruising at around 70kts usually

Comment: If you're concentrating on a "Time to impact" counter, then you're using electronic conspicuity  devices all wrong! Eyes outside.

Comment: A relevant factor may be how many *unequipped* aircraft may be likely to present, none of which you'll detect if your eyes are mostly inside the cockpit!  Ditto for large birds for that matter...

Comment: @DeltaLima I don't see how this can't be opinion based. Your answer, as well argued as it is, is opinion-based, based on suppositions and feel-goods. It's akin to asking someone when to flare. There are lots of good answers, and they're pretty much all right. Some people do it with a formula and others do it by feel, but there is no general answer. Maybe if the question narrows down, e.g. to pull from my example "when does the FAA teach to flare" instead of "when should I flare?" Otherwise, this is great stuff, but it's forum stuff not Q&A fodder.

Comment: @KennSebesta I agree that the answer is to a certain degree opinion-based and I don't think there is any problem with that. This discussion is as old as [this site](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/329/19), and [pre-dates it in the stackexchange ecosystem](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The off-topics guidance in the help centre for this site states: `You should only ask questions that can be factually answered or seek opinions that are supported by facts and principles.`. Not every question that is opinion-based is problematic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you arrived at the 5 NM / 2500 ft numbers, but it sounds like a plausible ratio. However, what is really important is the distance magnitude here. 5NM / 2500 ft is the same ratio as 10NM / 5000ft or 2 NM/1000ft. The former is giving you many more nuisance alerts than the latter, but the latter will be giving you less time to react.

What you have here is the typically challenge that every designer of a safety relevant alerting system is always faced with: a trade-off between the number of false alerts (nuicance) and the number of missed alerts (dangerous).

To arrive at a good distance and vertical settings, you would need to look at 2 things:

1. what is the time that is needed to react to an alert and be able to execute an avoidance manoeuvre, and
2. what is the relative speed that the two aircraft move at?

For the first part, let's look at the timeline of events leading to a safe outcome. I don't only look at the pilot's reaction to the alert here, I also look at the time to generate the alert. In the second part I will look at relative speeds, and combine the two to arrive at an alerting distance. I ignore vertical distance here, I leave that up to you.

According to the [SafeSky website](https://www.safesky.app/en/fonctionnement), SafeSky does not rely on sensors on-board, instead it collects aircraft surveillance data from various sources and transmits that data over a mobile phone connection to an App in the cockpit.

- The latency of the whole alerting chain is unclear from SafeSky's website, but let's assume it takes 5 seconds<sup>1</sup>:

  - between the GPS on-board of an intruding aircraft determines it's position
  - forwards it to the transponder which then sends it out as an ADS-B message
  - to an ADS-B receiver which decodes it, and
  - forwards it over the internet to an ADS-B collection site
  - which processes it and forwards it to the SafeSky servers,
  - which decode it and determine which subscribers need to be informed,
  - then again forward it to over the internet and
  - the mobile network to your 2G mobile phone connection, and
  - then the SafeSky app on-board compares it to your GPS position
  - determines that there is a need to alert the pilot and then,
  - it both visually and aurally alerts the pilot of the intruder
- Then, the pilot reacts to the alert by looking at the App's, and interprets the situation on the display. I assume this takes 3 seconds.
- The pilot then looks outside to visually acquire the intruding traffic, understand the relative motions and determine the best avoidance manoeuvre. Let's say this takes 5 seconds.
- The pilot initiates the avoidance manoeuvre and due to the dynamics of the aircraft, it takes 10 seconds to move out of the danger zone.

The above yields 23 seconds of latency, which I will conservatively stock up to 30 seconds for my own peace of mind<sup>2</sup>.

---

For the second part, let's take a look at the geometry.

A quick Google on geometry of mid-air collisions for GA gives me the following histogram:

[image: Histogram of geomtries for both in-pattern and out-of-pattern midair collisions]

<sup>source: Midair collisions: [Morris, Carl. (2005). Midair collisions: Limitations of the see-and-avoid concept in civil aviation. Aviation, space, and environmental medicine. 76. 357-65.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7907700_Midair_collisions_Limitations_of_the_see-and-avoid_concept_in_civil_aviation)</sup>

I recommend reading the article as it gives a good analysis of typical midair collision scenarios and their contributing factors.

As you can see (and as expected), most in-pattern collisions are head-tail and acute, and will include many of the the infamous *low-wing descents onto high-wing collision* geometries. These accidents will have low relative speed.

Out-of-pattern, the acute geometry is prevaillent, but head-on and obtuse geometries combined account for the majority of mid-air geometries.

If you want to be conservative, you account for the perfect head-on scenario and calculate with the sum of both aircraft's speed.
Assuming the head-on intruder aircraft is a jet travelling towards you at 275 knots true airspeed (KTAS), and you yourself are flying at 150 KTAS, we end up at a relative speed of 425 knots.
In 30 seconds, you will have gotten 425 / 3600 * 30 = 3.54 NM closer to each other. And so a setting of 3.6 NM should be a good starting point for such a scenario.

However, if you are flying in an airspace with virtually no fast traffic and you yourselve are traveling at lower speeds, you can adjust the alerting distance to reduce the number of nuisance alerts. Let's say you are doing 120KTAS and so does everybody else, you could reduce to 240/3600 * 30 = 2 NM.

If this approach is still giving too many nuisance alerts, you can make educated adjustments. For example, you can argue that for head-on and obstuse scenarios, the intruder is in your primary field of vision, and may likely be caught with standard see and avoid techniques, and can be easily tracked during avoidance manoeuvring. Instead of taking 5+10 seconds for visually acquisition of the traffic and manoeuvring, you may be comfortable with a total of 10 seconds.

Here you are trading nuisance level with risk level. It's your judgement call: too many nuisance alert will cause you to eventually ignore even important alerts, but too low of a look-ahead time will not give you enough time to react.

---

### IMPORTANT

As a final word of caution, and I can't stress this enough: **please don't rely fully on a technology for traffic avoidance**. Current traffic detection technologies are not reliable enough to ensure safe flight on their own. They are there to complement See-and-avoid. **See-and-avoid** is your primary way of noticing  and avoiding other traffic when flying VFR and even in IFR flight, S&A has its place!

Adding traffic detection technology can improve your See & Avoid performance, but be very aware of the following:

1. the SafeSky technology (as most other similar traffic detection systems) relies on other aircraft being equiped with some type of transmitting device to be visible. Not all aircraft are equiped with supported transmitters.
2. Even if other traffic is using a technology supported by SafeSky, it is not guaranateed that SafeSky will receive the data from that aircraft. Not all aircraft are within coverage of the receiver network.
3. Even if SafeSky receives the data from the other traffic, the connection to your device may be broken, or lack the performance to inform you in time.

As such, you have to keep telling yourself that you see only a partial traffic picture on your device. **[You have to keep looking outside](https://www.jbmdl.jb.mil/Portals/47/documents/AFD-160121-033.pdf)**.

This is easy if you often notice aircraft that are not shown on your traffic display, but as the technology improves, your mind will start to trust the technology, even though it is still unreliable.

If the technology tries to kill you once an hour, you will be on top of your game and probably fly safely for thousand hours. But if the technology tries to kill you only once every 100 hours, you will become complacent and need a lot of luck to make it to a thousand.

---

<sup>1</sup>The exact architecture and latency will be different for each surveillance source. Also, I have no knowledge about SafeSky sensor network nor processing logic. This is a very rough estimate.

<sup>2</sup>As always: since this a quick internet answer, the numbers above are not validated by thorough technical analysis and expert reviews as would normally be done when performing this kind of alerting threshold designs in my area of work. The numbers are merely made up by me, based on my experience, gut feeling and sometime failing memory. Don't just trust everything I write here, please do your own validation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer DeltaLima, this was a great read.... S&A is of course, important, but you cannot see behind you and either above or below you depending on wing set-up, so as the linked article mentions, it is a limiting technique :) Many thanks again!